# Answering question in comments - by linking to offsite resource

Tags: discussion, comment-flags, on-hold

I've noticed this pattern of behaviour a few times recently<sup>1</sup>. Since I just had a flag<sup>2</sup> declined for highlighting it (admittedly, this is the first time I decided to *do something* about it), I thought I ought to ask what the right approach to dealing with this should be.

The pattern is:

- Someone asks a question
- Question receives various close votes, resulting in it being placed on hold
- Someone else shows up and comments along the lines of "I can't believe other people voted to close this question. Here's my answer" where the answer is a link to an off-site resource (usually some kind of code-dump site)

My understanding is that we don't want people answering in the comments. We don't want people answering *full stop* when the question is on hold. And we don't want answers that are just links to off-site resources.

So if flagging the comment is wrong, what is the *right* course of action for me to take here?

---

<sup>1</sup>Different users, so far as I can recollect.

<sup>2</sup>I flagged as "In need of moderator intervention" with my comment as:

> The question has been closed. Rather than respecting the group's decision making (or wait reopen), this user has decided to effectively provide an answer off-site and link to it in the comments.

Which was at the limit of the amount of text that can be included in a flag.

Comment: What did you flag the comment as? did you use a mod flag?

Comment: @SurajRao - I did use a mod flag. it didn't seem to fit the other flagging options.

Comment: Pedantic nitpicking footnote: The primary issue with "respecting the group's decision making" here is that there was a definite decision in the first place, in the form of actual closure (even though it is subject to revision through reopen votes). I mention that because not long ago I have seen someone suggest that answering a question with close votes *that is still open* would be inappropriate for going against the community judgement -- that is not at all what you are saying here, but I feel it might be worth it to explicitly rule out that (mis)interpretation.

Comment: @duplode - I was trying to convey this at the end of the second bullet. The question has been placed on hold. The reason the user chose to post in the comments is because the answer box isn't available to them, and the lack of availability of the answer box is a deliberate part of the design of the site.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Very well said. This is one of the cases in which the site mechanics and formalities serve to draw the line in an effective way.

Comment: _"My understanding is that we don't want people answering in the comments."_ I believe this strongly but have found a surprising number of people disagreeing. _"We don't want people answering full stop when the question is on hold."_ Some even use this _as a reason to answer in comments_, which is double-ungood, but again is disturbingly popular. I've almost given up on this tbh - the days of SE's Q&A model being understood and desired by contributors and even some of the staff seem to be long gone. Shrug.

Comment: @SurajRao: Whenever I have flagged answers-in-comments, the flag has been declined and I've been told off for "abusing" the flagging system. I mean you really just can't win....

Comment: What harm do you believe this does? The question is being closed and will be removed from the site, why is it harmful for the OP to get at least some help?  Quite often these sorts of comment answers are a link to a tutorial or manual that gives the OP enough information to go on to ask a good question.

Comment: (although ---- it depends. It may be legitimate to point out the typo in the comment to make others aware of the typo, and close it. (because afaik there are no other better way anyway :/ ) Thoughts? )

Comment: (what is a "code-dump site"? Pastebin? )

Comment: @JeffUK - because if the commenter believes that the question is in someway answerable, they ought to be *working with the OP to improve the question to the point it gets reopened and then providing a useful answer on the site*. Instead, they link to a bunch of code based on their (usually unconfirmed) assumptions about the question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "I believe [we don't want people answering in the comments] strongly but have found a surprising number of people disagreeing" -- One complication is that, in my view, the appropriateness of doing that depends on the specific situation. It is one thing to e.g. point out the typo when closing as "off-topic/typo", or to post the outline of a partial, not yet satisfactory, answer to a hard question in the comments. It is another thing entirely to just go "I don't like this closure! You can find my answer [here]".

Comment: @user202729 - pastebin would be one example. There are also online compiler sites as another.

Comment: What do you mean by *full stop*? Is it just for emphasis? AFAIK, answering in the comments is the only way to circumvent the "on hold" thing.

Comment: @anatolyg Wrong. The proper way to circumvent the "on hold" is to **edit** the question to an answerable state, vote to reopen it, and then post the answer.

Comment: this is off topic but your profile pictures mask is off centre can you please fix that my ocd is going insane

Comment: So, what do you mean by "We don't want people answering *full stop* when the question is on hold"?

Comment: @anatolyg Not the OP, but it most likely is just emphasis.

Comment: @user202729: You mean like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247446/155739) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320364/560648)? Doesn't _seem_ to have functioned as a solution, despite my best efforts.

Comment: (I just upvote the comment above to draw people attention to read the linked Q&A 's)

Comment: Some more links. [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260743/how-to-handle-questions-that-have-answers-in-the-languages-documentation) [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat) [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments).

Comment: (Note for readers: This concerns "too broad" type of questions, unlike the other linked question which concerns "highly non-trivial and high-quality" or "trivial that is answerable in the documentation  or is just a typo" question)

Comment: There is some failed premise here. First, comments are not answers. Second, link only answers are converted to comments as the right way of doing things. Third, linking in comments to off site resources is not harming anything (in fact, it probably builds SO's pagerank at Google).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Did you just answer this question by linking to an off-site resource? ;)

Comment: What if you don't have the time for writing a proper answer, but can quickly give the OP a link to relevant documentation? I've done that a [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36626596/sql-server-from-two-rows-one-column-to-one-row-two-columns) of [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36137814/view-that-shows-whats-not-imported-yet), on both open and closed question. Never thought it might actually bother anyone that there's a link to official documentation in the comments...

Comment: @ZoharPeled That is fine. What Damien is describing is a different scenario: when, behind the link, there is a "proper answer" written by the comment author and uploaded to e.g. GitHub Gists or Pastebin.

Comment: I answer your question in a comment, before I vote for close as dupe: in general, if a question can get an answer in a comment, then it could get an answer also as a regular answer. And the only reason I can imagine to avoid it is the irrational urge to avoid avid answerers to collect rep. In my opinion, this irrational urge harms much more the SE as the little count of the little bit problematic questions. I hope you are satisfied my **answer**. And now I vote your question to close as dupe.

Comment: @unutbu: Good one :P

Comment: User asks bad question, I vote to close. But I know a good offsite article that might lead to an answer and hopefully helps the asker. Seems like I'm following the newest SO guidelines of "be nice" by posting the link and still helping SO by voting to close. Being nice if lucky means the asker gets some help and hopefully eventually is a better developer who will someday contribute to SO?

Comment: @gman - but in this case, the commenter was a contributor to SO who disagreed with the close vote and wrote a specific blog post which started along the lines of "this *should* be my answer on SO but other (wrong) people wrongly closed the question before I could provide it" (I.e. their tone hardly fitted with "be nice" but by making it an offsite resource, they also absented themselves from SO feedback). They didn't just find an offsite resource, they created one because they disagreed with a policy or its application.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** - The right course of action is to ignore those comments. If they say something rude/abusive, then flag that. But other than that, those comments are a waste of time.

---

Just to keep things in perspective, the purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a library of high-quality questions and answers. When questions are unsuitable for this purpose, they get closed and eventually deleted.

I'm mentioning this because some "new" users get an idea that the "old" users entertain themselves by forcing askers to dance to some mysterious set of arbitrary rules, those who misstep getting nailed with "You'll get no answers from us!" and multitudinous downvotes.

Nope. Withholding answers is not a weapon. The rules have meaning, and they all make sense if you keep the perspective of a library of high-quality questions and answers.

Most (if not all) close reasons are there to prevent answerers from wasting their time on bad questions. "Too broad", "Unclear", and "Duplicate" come to mind.

**If someone tries to circumvent rules to answer a closed question, they're probably wasting their time.** After all, the question has already been looked at by the community and deemed not worth it.

Back to comments: the reason people shouldn't answer in comments is that it's not as noticeable, it can't be voted on, can't be discussed as easily, and comments can get deleted at the drop of a moderator's hat. If someone answers in the comments, it's not that they're doing something *bad*, it's that they're *not doing something good*.

So, could the user whip the question into shape instead of commenting? Maybe. But we can't *make* them do it. This site is done on a voluntary basis. If it's any consolation, they can't earn any reputation from commenting.

**Flagging comments on closed questions is probably a waste of time, unless something is rude/abusive.** Flagging comments means that one our super-busy moderators would have to look at it and decide if it should be deleted. Most closed questions get deleted. That's wasting the moderators' time. So, if it's not rude/abusive, why bother?

One thing that I think is bad is if someone were to hang around on closed questions and confirm askers' suspicions that Stack Overflow has bad rules and discourage them from learning. That might be something to flag.

Comment: "One thing that I think is bad is if someone were to hang around on closed questions and confirm askers' suspicions that Stack Overflow has bad rules and discourage them from learning. That might be something to flag." -- Just to be sure: do you mean comments in the vein of "I really want to help you, but the swarm of pedants infesting this site is getting in the way"?

Comment: @duplode Yeah, something like that. Basically, people shouldn't try to discourage new users from using the site. Note that I'm not really sure what to flag it _as_ besides it being a mod flag. It may be worth a meta discussion (if it isn't one already). Being empathetic toward an asker is okay, but telling them, "This site is a hopeless mess, why don't you follow me on X other site..." - that's not a great thing to have going around.

Comment: [1/2] I remember having flagged a similar comment of this kind (as "not constructive" -- that was before the latest flag reform); the flag was accepted (the corresponding Meta discussion was in a now deleted rant by the comment author). Still, I'm also not sure on the grounds I'd use now to justify such a flag. "Inviting an unproductive meta discussion in the comments" might work, but I worry a bit about that leading to a slippery slope, in which reasonable comments such as "This question shouldn't be closed as [...] because [argument that accounts for the site guidelines]" also get flagged.

Comment: [2/2] On a tangential note, there is also a kind of comment which is vaguely similar to what you describe, but entirely benign: "While this is an interesting question, it isn't a good fit for the Stack Overflow format. You might want to post it on [some other site which is a sensible destination for the question]."

Comment: @duplode I bounced this off a moderator, and they said that flagging it with something like "Trying to discourage person from using the site" (or words to that effect; my memory is fuzzy and I can't find the link) is good enough. Maybe it's not necessary to justify it overmuch, as long as the comment looks bad and there are a couple more links to back it up. To your second part, yeah, there's a similarity. I think the line is disparaging Stack Overflow instead of saying "your question isn't a good fit". Can you have a R/A where the target is the site itself...? :)